# InputTextLayout takes 2 clicks to repond onclick

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a InputTextLayout in my layout file and I want it to perform something onclick through kotlin, the problem is it takes two clicks to perform the onclick. So I tried setting the focus of the edittext as false, it works but the edittext does not allow us to give input.

I have tried solutions like passing isFocusable = true, isFocusableInTouchMode = true, requestFocus() in onclick() function but did not work.

This is my xml code

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilPostArticleTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_separator_my_groups">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/titleEdittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:hint="Title"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:onClick="onOutClick"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:minHeight="40dp"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:textColorHint="#228B22" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and my onclick function in kotlin

```
@OnClick(R.id.tilPostArticleTitle)
fun onOutClick(view: View){
    mRecyclerViewMyGroups.visibility = View.GONE
    dropdownView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp)
    titleEdit.requestFocus()
    titleEdit.isFocusable = true
    titleEdit.isFocusableInTouchMode = true


}
```

Comment: You have set the onClick for the TextInputEditText and not for the TextInputLayout.

Comment: yes, because I have onClick in the TextInputEditText in my xml

Comment: TextInputLayout is a container and the TextInputEditText covers almost full area of  the TextInputLayout. How can you click on TextInputLayout? The click will be absorbed by the TextInputEditText.